# JAVA error occur while remote debugging

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to debug my web application which is deployed on aws server.
I do the following steps at **server** side:

```
1. export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
2. export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
3. catalina.sh jpda start
```

After doing this, I checked tomcat process in which it indicating that debugger is on.

At client side i used eclipse neon. In debug configuration of project, i mentioned ip address of `aws` server in host field and port of debugger in port field.

It gives me following **error**:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
>   org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException

Comment: isn't there any firewall restriction on the aws in regards to what ports are open to the outside world? Maybe the port cannot be accessed remotely.

Comment: As @sfat suggested, check if the port 8000 is opened in ec2 security group

Comment: I expose 8000 port on AWS

Answer (score 0):

@Chacko Mathew Suggested, it seems your security group is not open to allow traffic on port 8000.
Breaking down the steps needed to open your port.

TO enable this via this AWS console.

1. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances:sort=instanceId . Sign in with your creds.
2. Change the region as needed.
3. Select the instance that you need to debug on.
4. In the description tab find the `Security Groups` entry.
5. Click on the  attached security group.
6. Click on the Inbound tab.
7. Click on Edit inside the Inbound tab.
8. On the popup click `Add Rule`, Leave `Type` as `Custom TCP Rule`, `Protocol` as `TCP`, `Port Range` as 8000, Source `Custom` and your Public IP address, Add `Description` as needed.
9. Click Save.

That should do it, to find your IP address, just google `whats my ip`. It should you your public IP address.